# ComboBox DropDownList bug

Tags: c#, combobox

Combine FlatStyle: Flat with DropDownStyle: DropDownList result a bug.

[image: Look at this image.]

Steps to reproduce:

1. place a ComboBox
2. FlatStyle: Flat
3. DropDownStyle: DropDownList

How can I solve this?

Comment: works fine on my machine

Comment: sorry, I can't reproduce this either. have you tried this on other forms? In a new project? Also, does it stay if you move the control. Because I can create that look by making an empty label without autosize and a dark background color and placing it there.

Comment: It caused by a system setting which I reverted to original. The "bug" is disappeared. Thank you for your quick help.